# Replace duplicate lines with string by matching them with regular expression

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I have a number of lines that i get from a command output. They follow this pattern:

```
payload
constant value(u) constant(u)
payload
constant value(u) constant(u)
payload
```

In this example, (u) is an unknown character/characters.

What i care about is "payload", so i remove the "constant value(u) constant(u)" lines (by keeping every second line) using sed:

`sed -n '1~2!p'`

Sometimes, however, there is a duplicate "constant value(u) constant(u)" line and that makes sed to return all the following "constant value(u) constant(u)" lines instead of the "payload" lines .

I can use a regular expression to remove all "constant value(u) constant(u)" lines:

`sed '/^constant.*constant.*$/d'`

But the problem is that i must have a notion that this line was there, even if it's not a "payload" line, so i want to replace the content of this problematic duplicate line with some string. I want to replace only the "problematic" duplicate lines.

So, here is an example input in normal sutiation:

```
after 1 hour
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
after 2 hours
Cras id consequat nisl.
after 2 hours
Etiam non metus eu velit maximus dapibus.
after 1 hour
Etiam a mi quis ante congue posuere.
after 5 hours
Suspendisse et venenatis ipsum, aliquet pharetra tortor.
```

This is a "problematic" input:

```
after 1 hour
after 6 hours
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
after 2 hours
Cras id consequat nisl.
after 2 hours
Etiam non metus eu velit maximus dapibus.
after 1 hour
Etiam a mi quis ante congue posuere.
after 5 hours
Suspendisse et venenatis ipsum, aliquet pharetra tortor.
```

The desired output (in case of the problematic input above) is:

```
(no information)
after 6 hours
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
after 2 hours
Cras id consequat nisl.
after 2 hours
Etiam non metus eu velit maximus dapibus.
after 1 hour
Etiam a mi quis ante congue posuere.
after 5 hours
Suspendisse et venenatis ipsum, aliquet pharetra tortor.
```

How to approach this in the most efficient way? I guess i should match the "problematic" lines with regular expression and replace them with the desired string, but how?

Comment: Done. I updated the question.

Comment: Do problematic lines ever appear more than twice in a row? Can you have triplicates or more?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: And what should it produce? Do you ever have consecutive payloads without a constant to separate them?

Comment: Must you use sed for this? Have you considered other tools, like awk or even a shell script?

Comment: `awk 'x && $1 != x {print line} $1 == x {print "(no information)"} {x=$1; line=$0} END {print line}'`

Comment: @oguzismail why are you voting to close? He clarified what he was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will find 2 consecutive lines starting with `constant` and replace the 2nd one with `X`:

```
sed '/^constant.*$/ { N; s/\(^constant.*\n\)constant.*$/\1X/; }'
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the additional information you've provided, this should do the trick:

```
sed '/^after .*$/ { N; s/^after .*\(\nafter .*\)$/(no information)\1/; }'
```

**UPDATE #2**

Another solution provided by @potong in the comments:

```
sed -E '/^after/{N;s/.*(\nafter)/(no information)\1/;P;D}'
```

This will also work in cases where there are more than 2 "problematic" lines in a row and will replace all of them with `(no information)`.

Comment: I haven't downvoted yet, but this solution is platform-specific. It may work in GNU sed, but it doesn't work in macOS, FreeBSD (or other BSDs), solaris, etc.

Comment: @ghoti which part is GNU-specific?

Comment: @InnocentBystander - at first glance, the use of `\n` in the replacement string and the lack of a semicolon before the close-curly-brace. I haven't tested it.

Comment: @ghoti thanks. Well the semicolon is simple to fix. Newline is a bit trickier, but IIRC can be done as well with shell literal.

Comment: A simple addition of `;P;D` before the closing `}` will ensure 1,2 or more of the consecutive problematic input will be catered for e.g. `sed -E '/^after/{N;s/.*(\nafter)/(no information)\1/;P;D}' file`

Comment: @potong thank you. I used your "trick" to capture newline on the input side and reuse it on the output side to make it POSIXly correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are the duplicate lines next to each other? If so, just run the file through uniq first